# CakePHP Audit Log Plugin user authentication

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to implement the Audit Trail plugin - https://github.com/robwilkerson/CakePHP-Audit-Log-Plugin

It all works great, however i can't get the user authentication working by following the instructions i get the following error -

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CakeErrorController::currentUser()
```

I have followed the instructions by adding

```
protected function currentUser() {
      $user = $this->Auth->user();
      return $user[$this->Auth->userModel]; # Return the complete user array
}
```

and adding

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        ...
        if( !empty( $this->data ) && empty( $this->data[$this->Auth->userModel] ) ) {
          $this->data[$this->Auth->userModel] = $this->currentUser();
        }
   }
```

to my appController, has anyone implemented this before or recognise the error?

Comment: the CakeErrorController probably does not extend the AppController and therefore does not have this method.

Comment: My CakeErrorController contains 'App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');', any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For Cakephp 2.4 you have to do some changes in order to work with the Auth component:

In the AppModel:

```
public function currentUser() {
  $userId = AuthComponent::user('id');

  //Get the information of the user
  $currentUser = $this->importModel('User')->find('first', array(
      'conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$userId),
  ));

  //Return all the User
  return $currentUser['User'];
}
```

And now in your AppController:
The true is you don't need to do anything else in your controller, it's just to prevent some problem. So, **OPTIONAL**:

```
  if( !empty( $this->request->data ) && empty( $this->request->data[$this->Auth->userModel] ) ) {
        $user['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->request->data[$this->Auth->userModel] =  $user;
    }
```

It works for me.

Comment: How about just `public function currentUser() { return AuthComponent::user(); }` instead. Nothing is actually required in controller as already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the `currentUser()` function to your `AppController`, it has to be in your `AppModel`. Here's what my `currentUser()` function looks like using CakePHP 2.3:

```
public function currentUser() {
    return array('id' => AuthComponent::user('id'));
}
```